# React Native Picker select: are there any callbacks available for Android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, picker, react-native-picker-select

I'm using [react-native-picker-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select) in my React Native app, and the two main callbacks I'm using for iOS are `onClose()` and `onDonePress()`. However, these are iOS only. Is there some approach you can use with Android to trigger a function when the user has closed the picker or pressed `Done`? I know you can use `onValueChange()`, but this doesn't get triggered when the user is done, just when they iterate through the options in the picker.

Comment: It look android didn't need to touch the "done" button, it doesn't have that button, didn't it?

Answer (score 1):

onClose is iOS only, I was able to get a similar behavior for Android using onBlur of touchableWrapperProps (please make sure to add fixAndroidTouchableBug).

```
const handleOnClose = () => {};

<RNPickerSelect
          onClose={handleOnClose} // iOS only
          fixAndroidTouchableBug
          touchableWrapperProps={{ onBlur: handleOnClose }} // Android only
        />
```